# After using Auto-rename L-R, Simmetrize creates disconnected, symmetric moving bones

Tags: rigging

In the following picture you can see that when I move the root of the simmetrized part, the simmetrized bones (on the right in the image) don't follow anymore the "neck", and instead move simmetrically, detaching completely from it.

[image]

Is this correct behavior?

Comment: hello, could you please share this part? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Yes, here it is: https://pasteall.org/blend/4a979656f77d4a3d80581c861cecb1d5

Comment: the bones on the right should follow but as the symmetrize option is enabled it looks like its the normal behavior (which is weird as it disconnects the bone from its parent, but it is still a child)